# Why is sed's + regex operator not matching any leading whitespace, but * is?

Tags: regex, replace, sed, regex-greedy

I thought + and * are both greedy.  Why does + not seem to match anything in this context, but * does?

```
$ cat test
     a
$ sed -i 's/^[ \t]+//g' test
$ cat test
     a
$ sed -i 's/^[ \t]*//g' test
$ cat test
a
```

Those are just spaces (not tabs) before `a`, but tabs alone, or a mix of both, results in the same thing.

This is on `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`.

Comment: Because the quantifier `+` doesn't exist in BRE (Basic Regular Expression)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+` is not recognised in Basic Regular Expressions, which is the default for `sed`. Using the `+` is matching the literal `+` character.

Use `-E` option to force `sed` to recognise ERE (Extended Regular Expressions).

Comment: I guess I was so used to using extended engines, I never realized that!  Thanks!

Comment: Wait, Dana's answer works, doesn't that seem to contradict this?

Comment: No - "enhanced basic regular expressions" extend the BRE with the functionality of the ERE, but they couldn't change the `+` because of backward compatibility. It's all there, in newer tools, but looks funny. tl;dr: Both Dana's and my approach work, depends just how many backslashes you want to write. :P

Comment: See also the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#BRE-vs-ERE): in GNU sed, BRE and ERE have exactly the same capabilities and differ only in what has to be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the '+' with a backslash `\+`

```
sed -i 's/^[ \t]\+//g' test
```

Comment: That's a GNU extension to basic regular expressions and might not work in every sed.

Comment: @BenjaminW. that's good to note.  In this case of my question though, I did specify I was using GNU sed, so this is still valid.